# How to click tabbar item and let it have push animation by Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitabbarcontroller

I have few UINavigationControllers embed in a TabbarControlller.
If I want to click my tabbar Items and make transition animation like push  viewcontroller animation.
Have any idea to do it?

Comment: First of all, it will be a very weird user experience if you have a navigation animation on Tab Item click. After animation do you want the tab bar still be shown?

Comment: @Adithya Yes, tabbar and navigationbar always shown, just the viewcontroller has push animation.